# Azure Functions not using latest binary

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am building a Function App in C# with a compiled library. I deploy the code from the CLI and that's all fine.
Checking the file system with KUDU I can see all the files are updated, the `*.dll` is updated (the timestamp), but executing the function I get a result from an earlier build.
I execute the function locally from Visual Studio and everything is fine and outputs are as expected.
I can sometimes get the new build used by restarting the site from KUDU, but that's really not desired.
Any idea? I never had these issues when deploying through Github.

Comment: Are you using a Web Application project or a Functions Project (.funproj)?

Comment: Web App @MichaëlHompus

Comment: When you go to your Function App in the portal, which version of it do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your assembly deployed? If deploying the assembly to a folder outside of the actual function folder, please add that to the `watchDirectories` configuration in your `host.json` file.

You can find more information about that setting [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/host.json).

Comment: The DLL sits in the root, yes.<br>
Why is this different when deploying from Github?